# How can I run the "tar -czf" command in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, tar

I am currently running a computer which has access to only Windows.

I have to submit a folder after running `tar -czf` on it.

How can I do this in Windows, do I have any options?

Comment: Note that `tar` is now available in windows by default, so you can use it directly from the Command Prompt or from PowerShell

Answer (score 14):

If all you want is to create a tar.gz (also called tgz) file, then you can use 7Zip from http://www.7-zip.org/

To run like "tar -czf" you need to chain two 7z calls:

```
7z -ttar a dummy c:\my\path\* -so | 7z -si -tgzip a x.tgz
```

This creates a file **x.tgz** containing all data from **c:\my\path\**.

The -so redirects the output to stdout and the -si option picks that data up.

Comment: you should have definitely more upvotes

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Tar for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gtar.htm).

> The GNU Tar program provides the ability to create tar archives, as well as various other kinds of manipulation. For example, you can use tar on previously created archives to extract files, to store additional files, or to update or list files which were already stored.
>
> The Win32 port can only create tar archives, but cannot pipe its output to other programs such as gzip or compress, and will not create tar.gz archives; you will have to use or simulate a batch pipe. BsdTar does have the ability to direcly create and manipulate .tar, .tar.gz, tar.bz2, .zip, .gz and .bz2 archives, understands the most-used options of GNU Tar, and is also much faster; for most purposes it is to be preferred to GNU Tar.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 4):

As of **build 17063** (2017), Windows has `tar.exe` built-in ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/community/team-blog/2017/20171219-tar-and-curl-come-to-windows)). So you can directly use `tar` commands:

Creating a zip file:

```
tar -cf [output.zip] [folder/file_name]
```

Extracting a zip file:

```
tar -xf [file.zip]
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) or [MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys), they usually come with `tar` utility.

Answer (score 2):

`tar -czf` creates a gzipped tar file, usually the extension `.tar.gz` or `.tgz` is used.

Windows has no built-in support for creating (or reading) tar files or gzipped files, and Microsoft offers no tools for this either.

This format can be created using, e.g., 7Zip; see for example this blog post: [http://www.tmsnetwork.org/blog/creating-targz-archive-easily-windows](https://web.archive.org/web/20110210015512/http://www.tmsnetwork.org/blog/creating-targz-archive-easily-windows) (archive.org copy: apparently this blog disappeared).  Many more tools could be used, see [http://www.7zip.com/type/5/TAR](https://web.archive.org/web/20130210152618/http://www.7zip.com/type/5/TAR) (archive.org copy: apparently 7zip.com disappeared, to be replaced by [7-zip.org](http://7-zip.org)).

Comment: I think he is asking for a *native* way to do it. (instead of 3rd party)

Answer (score 1):

You can also download and install 7zip. http://www.7zip.org.  With it, you can both unpack and pack many different compression types including gzip.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most elegant way to do it would be to install Linux subsystem for Windows.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide#enable-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux-feature-gui

Please keep in mind that this is beta.

There are also lots of ways to get Linux functionality:

- MSYS
- Cygwin
- Virtual Machines

There are lots of tools and applications that do this.

Answer (score 0):

Make these steps:

- Download libarchive https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/libarchive/2.4.12-1/libarchive-2.4.12-1-setup.exe/download
- Then`"%programfiles(x86)%\gnuwin32\bin\bsdtar.exe" czf path_to_compressed_file path_to_folder`